# Have an extra data member only when something is active in c++

Tags: c++

I have an implementation of a queue, something like `template <typename T> queue<T>` with a `struct QueueItem { T data;}` and I have a separate library that times the passage of data across different places (including from one producer thread to consumer thread via this queue). In order to do this, I inserted code from that timing library into the push and pop functions of the queue so that when they assign a `BufferItem.data` they also assign an extra member i added of type `void*` to some timing metadata from that library. I.e. what used to be something like:

```
void push(T t)
{
  QueueItem i;
  i.data = t;
  //insert i into queue
}
```

became

```
void push(T t)
{
  QueueItem i;
  i.data = t;

  void* fox = timinglib.getMetadata();
  i.timingInfo = fox;
  //insert i into queue
}
```

with QueueItem going from

```
struct QueueItem
{
 T data;
}
```

to

```
struct QueueItem
{
  T data;
  void* timingInfo;
}
```

What I would like to achieve, however, is the ability to swap out of the latter struct in favor of the lighter weight struct whenever the timing library is not activated. Something like:

```
if timingLib.isInactive()
 ;//use the smaller struct QueueItem
else
 ;//use the larger struct QueueItem
```

as cheaply as possible. What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Is this something that is done at compile-time or run-time?

Comment: Run-time because the timing library will shut itself down if it's too much overhead..at which point the void* will just be null and a freerider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a struct that is big and small at the same time, obviously, so you're going to have to look at some form of inheritance or pointer/reference, or a union.

A union would be ideal for you if there's "spare" data in T that could be occupied by your timingInfo. If not, then it's going to be as 'heavy' as the original.

Using inheritance is also likely to be as big as the original, as it'll add a vtable in there which will pad it out too much.

So, the next option is to store a pointer only, and have that point to the data you want to store, either the data or the data+timing. This kind of pattern is known as '[flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)' - where common data is stored separately to the object that is manipulated. This might be what you're looking for (depending on what the timing info metadata is).

The other, more complex, alternative is to have 2 queues that you keep in sync. You store data in one, and the other one stores the associated timeing info, if enabled. If not enabled, you ignore the 2nd queue. The trouble with this is ensuring the 2 are kept in sync, but that's a organisational problem rather than a technical challenge. Maybe create a new Queue class that contains the 2 real queues internally.

Comment: I like the flyweight idea but the call to push(const T& value) stores a copy of value whereas the timing library metadata returned by timingLib.getMetadata() is a void* later cast on the other end to a struct someStruct*...a pointer wouldn't work for both though unless i do QueueItem.data = libActive() ? new JointStruct(value,metadata()) : new T(value)

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by just confirming my assumption that this needs to be a runtime choice and you can't just build two different binaries with timing enabled/disabled. That approach eliminates as much overhead in any approach as possible.

So now let's assume we want different runtime behavior. There will need to be runtime decisions, so there are a couple options. If you can get away with the (relatively small) cost of polymorphism then you could make your queue polymorphic and create the appropriate instance once at startup and then its `push` for example either will or won't add the extra data.

However if that's not an option I believe you can use templates to help accomplish your end, although there will likely be some up-front work and it will probably increase the size of your binary with the extra code.

You start with a template to add timing to a class:

```
template <typename Timee>
struct Timed : public Timee
{
    void* timingInfo;
};
```

Then a timed QueueItem would look like:

```
Timed<QueueItem> timed_item;
```

To anything that doesn't care about the timing, this class looks exactly like a `QueueItem`: It will automatically upcast or slice to the parent as appropriate. And if a method needs to know the timing information you either create an overload that knows what to do for a `Timed<T>` or do a runtime check (for the "is timing enabled" flag) and downcast to the correct type.

Next, you'll need to change your `Queue` instantiation to know whether it's using the base `QueueItem` or the `Timed` version. For example, a very very rough sketch of a possible mechanism:

```
template <typename Element>
void run()
{
    Queue<Element> queue;

    queue.setup();
    queue.process();
}

int main()
{
    if(do_timing)
    {
        run<Timed<QueueItem> >();
    }
    else
    {
        run<QueueItem>();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You would "likely" need a specialization for `Queue` when used with `Timed` items unless getting the metadata is stateless in which case the `Timed` constructor can gather the info and self-populate itself when created. Then `Queue` just stays the same and relies on which instantiation you're using.